# unity new input system invoke unity event triggers only one function only once

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the new input system to invoke unity events but for some reason, after triggering one event, no other can be triggered.
To be more precise, I am trying to combine the input system with a slightly modified version of the undo/redo system from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1BocNFIkwI&t=313s)

Firstly, I used `public static List<ICommand> Undoable;` and `public static List<ICommand> Redoable;` instead of the `public static List<ICommand> CommandHistory` shown in the video.

an example of the functions that I try to trigger:
(this is from the Test class)

```
int i = 0;
public void Execute()
{
    Test();
}

private void Test()
{
    i++;
    Debug.Log($"test No.{i}"); 
}

public void Undo()
{
    Test();
}
```

which I try to use from the CommandInvoker

```
public void Test()
{
    CommandInvoker.AddCommand(new Test());
}
```

then I try to use undo on it:

```
public void Undo(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
{
    Debug.Log(CommandInvoker.Undoable.Count - 1);

    ICommand c = CommandInvoker.Undoable[CommandInvoker.Undoable.Count - 1];

    c.Undo();

    CommandInvoker.Undoable.Remove(c);

    CommandInvoker.Redoable.Add(c);
}
```

I even added the callbackContext just to be safe, but it did not help at all.

I don't know what's wrong with the code, so I added a few debug logs:

`Debug.Log($"buffer count after adding command: {commandBuffer.Count}");` in the `AddCommand()`

`Debug.Log($"buffer count after execution: {commandBuffer.Count}");` to the `update()`

and finaly, `Debug.Log($"undoable actions: {Undoable.Count}");` after i add c to the list in the `Update()`

This is what I got in the console:
invoking the test action for the 1st time:

> buffer count after adding command: 1
>
> buffer count after adding command: 2
>
> test No.1
>
> buffer count after execution: 1
>
> undoable actions: 1
>
> buffer count after execution: 0
>
> undoable actions: 2
>
> undoable actions: 3
> invoking the test action for the 2nd time:
>
> undoable actions: 4
>
> undoable actions: 5
>
> undoable actions: 6
> after invoking the undo action:
>
> -1
>
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index
>
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException while executing 'performed' callbacks of 'keybinds and shortcuts/Undo[/Keyboard/ctrl,/Keyboard/z]'
>
> -1
>
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index
>
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException while executing 'canceled' callbacks of 'keybinds and shortcuts/Undo[/Keyboard/ctrl,/Keyboard/z]'

Apart from the, out off range errors, which I will try to fix after resolving the first issue: the test action only executes once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So anyway, it turns out that turning your computer off and on really does wonders to some errors.